# Phone BackKey Functionality in Android Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

Please help me on this.....

I am using phonegap-1.1.0v . In my application i have multiple HTML file. Each file is a single page 
    Each page contains the home button on top of every HTML page.

```
when i  moved from Homepage -- > screen B --> Again Homepage --> screen c

when i pressed Back key on Screen c it goes back to Homepage but when i press the Backkey again it goes to Screen B and the Homepage. 

 For MY solution i requires when i press the Back key from home screen it always need to Flash screen page (or) it should get exit from the application.
```

Thanks in Advance.............:)

Answer (score 0):

```
//Deviceready function
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {

                          document.addEventListener("backbutton", go_back, false);

                          }, false);


function go_back(){
    // Put your code when back key is press
    // U can use window.location="home.html" to change page or something else
    // If u want to exit then use "device.exitApp();"
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is the solution given in all the refs but it is not working for me. If you have any sample code . Please share it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e){
    if($.mobile.activePage.is('#homepage')){
        e.preventDefault();
        navigator.app.exitApp();
    }
    else {
        navigator.app.backHistory()
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ,,,Can you please share me some sample working project for refs??

Comment: No.... Not yet... If any working sample code would have been there... we will take that one has sample and will work on it...

Comment: Ya...we tried but it is not working... and also navigator.app.exitApp() is not working at all.. i am using cordova-2.7.0

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to take a global Boolean variable and when you reach at home make it true and check this variable every time when you press back button like :

```
if (device.platform == 'android') 
{
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false); 

    function onBackKeyDown(e) 
    {
        if(isHome)
        {
            navigator.app.exitApp();
        }
        else
        {
            navigator.app.backHistory();
            //What you want when its not home page
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am getting the Uncaught reference error at EXT. At the same time I am using cordova-2.7.0 . It dont understand what is device. (After i removed the device platform if stmt). I ended up with EXT uncaught ref error. Please give some suggestions for this...